# Combine Multiple row into single row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, xhtml

I have a table like this

```
ItemName  header1  header2  header3

item1      0        0        1

item2      1        0        0

item1      1        0        0

item3      1        0        0

item2      0        1        0

item1      0        1        0
```

I need to combine the table rows like this

```
ItemName  header1 header2  header3

item1       1       1        1
item2       1       1        0
item3       1       0        0
```

Firstly i converted table into array of json using

```
var table = $('#Tbl').tableToJSON();
```

Now i have array of jsons and have to sum the duplicated rows

```
table=[{[{ItemName:item1},{header1:0},{header2:0},{header3:1}]},{[{ItemName:item2},{header1:1},{header2:0},{header3:0}]},{[{ItemName:item1},{header1:1},{header2:0},{header3:0}]},{[{ItemName:item3},{header1:1},{header2:0},{header3:0}]},{[{ItemName:item2},{header1:0},{header2:1},{header3:0}]},{[{ItemName:item1},{header1:0},{header2:1},{header3:0}]}];
```

i need the output like this

```
table=[{[{ItemName:item1},{header1:1},{header2:1},{header3:1}]},{[{ItemName:item2},{header1:1},{header2:1},{header3:0}]},{[{ItemName:item3},{header1:1},{header2:0},{header3:0}]}];
```

any answers please help me

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried to solve it up to now?

Comment: i used for loop to get the rows and if condition to compare the duplication , but i dont have a idea to combine the rows

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: i need to avoid the duplication in 1st column

Comment: i need to add values of duplicate column

Comment: can you please share your progress

Comment: sorry Lakshay cant understand ur comment

Comment: i mean can you pls share what code you have tried in a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to loop over the array and sum the values depending upon the criteria.

I have implemented a simple example in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/devoq/2/edit)

You can also use libraries like JSLINQ, BreezeJS for this, if you have some heavy filtering to do.